# How to get a mentioned user's avatar URL with discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, avatar

How can I get a mentioned user's avatar?
I can get a mentioned user's ID, but I can't find out how to use it like `message.author.avatar_url`.
Can I make this into `(Userid).author.avatar_url`?

I already got the mentioned user's ID by slicing the message's content.

Comment: It seems this question may have been answered on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/74bb4z/retrieve_a_mentioned_users_avatar_using_discordpy/). If you are able to find the answer there, you should answer your own queston here with the relevant information and accept the answer

Answer (score 4):

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@client.command(name='avatar', help='fetch avatar of a user')
async def dp(ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.message.author
    userAvatar = member.avatar_url
    await ctx.send(userAvatar)
```

The command will be something like => '-avatar' or '-avatar [user]'

P.s. Don't use [ ] after '-avatar' and before mentioning the user

If a user is not mentioned, it will fetch the avatar of the user sending the command

Answer (score 2):

```py
author = ctx.message.author
pfp = author.avatar_url
```

`Author` creates an object and can be used a string e.g `username#0000`

`pfp` (profile picture) is an asset that can be used in an embed for example

```
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url=pfp)

await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [the commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html), you can use a [`MemberConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter) or [`UserConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.UserConverter) to get the [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) or [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) object, respectively. Otherwise, you can use the [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) attribute of the [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) object to get a list of the `Member`s that were mentioned in the message.

If you have the user ID already, you can use of the methods covered in the [How do I get a specific model? section of the FAQ in the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-a-specific-model) to retrieve the `Member` or `User` object.

You can then use the `avatar_url` attribute of the `Member` or `User` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
author = message.author
await message.channel.send(author.avatar_url)
```

On use message args

Answer (score 0):

If you're using discord.py v2 it is: `message.author.avatar`.

Check this: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member

Answer (score 0):

for discord.py v2, use `member.avatar` not `member.avatar_url`

here's an example

```py
@bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.message.author
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_image(url=member.avatar)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

EDIT: for if you're using discord-py-slash-commands the following example should work for you
https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="avatar", description="gets mentioned users avatar")
async def avatar(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
    if not member:
        member = interaction.user
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_image(url=member.avatar)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```