# how can i get joined user name and avatar url with discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

i want on member join bot create a welcome image with member avatar and name on it and send it to text channel but i couldn't find any way to get member name and avatar url (member.name or member.avatar_url doesn't works).
here is my code:

```
#update status with new member count

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    member = 0
    for guild in client.guilds:
        member += guild.member_count - 1
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity = discord.Activity(
        type = discord.ActivityType.watching,
        name = f'{member} Members'
    ))

#create a image with joined user avatar and username
    picture = Image.open(requests.get(member.avatar_url, stream=True).raw)
    text = "Welcome, " + member.name

    original_file_path = 'text.png'
    img = Image.open("default.png")


    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 72)
    draw.text((925,800), text, (255, 255, 255), font=font)


    back_im = picture.copy()
    back_im.paste(img, (925, 500))


    img.save(original_file_path)
```

Comment: Isn't this answers your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872089/how-to-get-a-mentioned-users-avatar-url-with-discord-py

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that you don't have `Intents.members` enabled.

You would have to do something like this:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True #Enables it

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

In addition, you would have to enable it in the **[developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)**.

[image: Enable Here]

You can find more information in the discord **[API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#need-members-intent)**.